# ORA-00904 INVALID IDENTIFIER oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I would like to update a table using a column that may not exists. I am doing this but getting an error, I tried to handle but still getting an exception. Is there a way to go about this? to update a table only if a column exists? I am a beginner in Oracle PL/SQL, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
declare
  column_not_exists_exception exception;
  pragma exception_init (column_not_exists_exception , -06550);
begin
 update table1 
 set column = case 
    when column_may_not_exists = 0 then 0 
    when column_may_not_exists = 1 then 1
    else 0 
 end;
exception when column_not_exists_exception then
 dbms_output.put_line('error column does not exists');
end;
```

The error I get is `ORA-06550 and ORA-00904 : "column_may_not_exists" : invalid identifier , cause: usually a pl/sql compilation error`

Comment: Why don't you know if the column exists or not?

Comment: Hi @jarlh, thanks for asking. The problem is that some sql scripts  are run multiple times on our oracle server including one that deletes the column. So after redeploying the sql , we have the error. We want to run all our sql scripts as many times and handle all exceptions and avoid errors..

Comment: I'm not an Oracle expert, but I assume you'll need dynamic SQL for this. I.e. create the statement run-time, after checking the dictionary if the column exists or not.

Comment: Right, that would be dynamic SQL. **However**, I'd say that your approach is wrong. Why would you want to ALTER TABLE and add (and then drop) columns in the table? Create a table with all columns you need and then just *use them*, so they'll always be available to you.

Comment: jarlh is correct, you would need to use dynamic SQL, and then catch the ORA-00904 not ORA-06550; or use conditional compilation. It seems like you're solving the wrong problem though - your schema, deployment and application scripts shouldn't need to guess the state, it should be stable and predicable - particularly regarding schema changes like adding or removing table and columns.

Comment: I think "dropping columns" and "running scripts that might reference those columns" do not go together. You're adding an unnecessary amount of complexity (and developer resources) to your scripts because of this. Oracle has other options  for this - have you considered making the columns [invisible](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/invisible-columns-12cr1) ? The columns will no longer be visible to the client but the scripts will not fail. No changes to your scripts needed

Comment: Thanks guys for your recommendations. I will look into them and propose some improvements to the team. Thanks!

Comment: `exception ...` block catches runtime exceptions, [this is explicitly documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-error-handling.html#GUID-343E0653-9BCE-48F5-A00A-795D77B96B44). PL/SQL is a compiled language, so invalid identifiers are compile-time errors. You need to handle them by the application issuing this code (deployment pipeline or your eyes and hands in case of manual activity). Also it is not clear what you want as a result of this approach. Test your changes in QA and handle this issue before deploying to prod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is certainly a strange requirement, but since PL/SQL must be valid at compilation time, you can't reference a non-existent column directly.

Thus you can do the following

```
SQL> create table t ( x int, y int );

Table created.

SQL> insert into t values (0,0);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> declare
  2    column_not_exists_exception exception;
  3    pragma exception_init (column_not_exists_exception , -904);
  4  begin
  5   execute immediate '
  6     update t
  7     set y = case
  8      when y = 0 then 10
  9      when y = 1 then 20
 10      else 30
 11   end';
 12   dbms_output.put_line('All good');
 13  exception
 14    when column_not_exists_exception then
 15     dbms_output.put_line('error column does not exists');
 16  end;
 17  /
All good

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> declare
  2    column_not_exists_exception exception;
  3    pragma exception_init (column_not_exists_exception , -904);
  4  begin
  5   execute immediate '
  6     update t
  7     set z = case
  8      when z = 0 then 10
  9      when z = 1 then 20
 10      else 30
 11   end';
 12   dbms_output.put_line('All good');
 13  exception
 14    when column_not_exists_exception then
 15     dbms_output.put_line('error column does not exists');
 16  end;
 17  /
error column does not exists

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```